# Difference using @Id and @EmbeddedId for a compound key

Tags: java, hibernate

I've created an entity that uses @Id to point to an @Embeddable compound key.  Everything I believe works fine as is.  However, after switching @Id to @EmbeddedId everything continues to work fine as far as I can tell.

**Before:**

```
@Entity
public final class MyEntity {
    private CompoundKey id;

    @Id
    public CompoundKey getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(CompoundKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

**After:**

```
@Entity
public final class MyEntity {
    private CompoundKey id;

    @EmbeddedId
    public CompoundKey getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(CompoundKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Is there a difference between using the @Id and @EmbeddedId annotations when referencing a compound key?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm actually surprised the **"before"** version is working. According to the specification, the correct way to map your `Embeddable` compound key is the **"after"** version. Quoting the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> Every entity must have a primary key.
>
> The primary key must be defined on the
>   entity that is the root of the entity
>   hierarchy or on a mapped superclass of
>   the entity hierarchy. The primary key
>   must be defined exactly once in an
>   entity hierarchy.
>
> **A simple (i.e., non-composite) primary
>   key must correspond to a single
>   persistent field or property of the
>   entity class. The `Id` annotation is
>   used to denote a simple primary key.**
>   See section 9.1.8.
>
> A composite primary key must
>   correspond to either a single
>   persistent field or property or to a
>   set of such fields or properties as
>   described below. A primary key class
>   must be defined to represent a
>   composite primary key. Composite
>   primary keys typically arise when
>   mapping from legacy databases when the
>   database key is comprised of several
>   columns. **The `EmbeddedId` and and
>   `IdClass` annotations are used to
>   denote composite primary keys. See
>   sections 9.1.14 and 9.1.15.**
>
> The primary key (or field or property
>   of a composite primary key) should be
>   one of the following types: any Java
>   primitive type; any primitive wrapper
>   type; `java.lang.String`;
>   `java.util.Date`; `java.sql.Date`. In
>   general, however, approximate numeric
>   types (e.g., floating point types)
>   should never be used in primary keys.
>   Entities whose primary keys use types
>   other than these will not be portable.
>   If generated primary keys are
>   used, only integral types will be
>   portable. If `java.util.Date` is used as
>   a primary key field or property, the
>   temporal type should be specified as
>   DATE.
>
> ...

And later:

> #### 9.1.14 EmbeddedId Annotation
>
> The `EmbeddedId` annotation is applied
>   to a persistent field or property of
>   an entity class or mapped superclass
>   to denote a composite primary key that
>   is an embeddable class. The embeddable
>   class must be annotated as
>   `Embeddable`.
>
> There must be only one `EmbeddedId`
>   annotation and no Id annotation when
>   the `EmbeddedId` annotation is used.

Comment: The "Before" approach is listed in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate" as the second of 3 approaches to using composite primary id

Answer (score 17):

I referred hibernate docs [Hiberate 3.5 annotations reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177) whereby there is the difference that with `@EmbeddedId` you can skip annotating the entity class `@Embeddable` but with `@Id` it's required.

I tried using `@Id` without `@Embeddable` it gives exception:

> org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Component

Just this and no extra info like the field or class name.

Well this behavior is as of Hibernate 4; I don't know about other JPA providers. I will test a few and update post accordingly if there are any more findings.