# JPA with Hibernate - Missing Column if implementing composite keys

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

JPA/Hibernate missing column

I am using JPA with Hibernate as the provider. I had an entity class that had a single id column as the primary key. This worked fine but i now had to modify it so the primary key is a composite key comprised of two columns. To implement the composite key i used th example shown here [how to create a composite primary key hibernate JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764204/how-to-create-a-composite-primary-key-hibernate-jpa/9765674#9765674)

Here are the final classes:

The Primary Key

```
@Embeddable
public class DocumentPK implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="P_ID")
    private String pId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name="P_NAME")
    private String pName;

    public DocumentPK() {
    }

    public DocumentPK(String pId, int pName) {
        this.pId = pId;
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public String getPId() {
        return pId;
    }

    public void setPId(String pId) {
        this.pId = pId;
    }

    public String getPName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setPName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (pId != null ? pId.hashCode() : 0);
        hash += (int) pName;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof DocumentPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        DocumentPK other = (DocumentPK) object;
        if ((this.pId == null && other.pId != null) || (this.pId != null && !this.pId.equals(other.pId))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.pName != other.pName) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ pId=" + pId + ", pName=" + pName + " ]";
    }    
}
```

After implementing the above primary key, i updated the Entity Class to 'embed' the primary key as shown below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOCUMENTS")

public class CustomerDocument implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6373600479711119252L;

    private     DocumentPK  id; 
    private     String  p_code;

    @EmbeddedId
    public DocumentPK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(DocumentPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="P_CODE")
    public String getPCode() {
        return p_code;
    }       
}
```

Now i have checked the 'DOCUMENTS' table and all columns are there. I even logged on to MySQL using the same user and i can see the table and the relevant columns. If i run the above it complains about not finding the P_ID column. Have i forgotten something somewhere?

```
18:30:45,279 ERROR [TestContextManager] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1d349e2] to prepare test instance [com.bt.msm.ds.dao.BatchNumberDaoTest@97d3f0]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [my-spring-ds.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [my-spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [msm-spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: pId in mydb.documents
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1174)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:883)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have anything to test this with right now, but try placing the `@EmbeddedId` on the id-field instead of the method. If it doesn't work, try this instead:

DocumentPK:

```
public class DocumentPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String pId;

    private String pName;
    /* The rest of the class, notice the missing annotations */
```

CustomerDocument:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOCUMENTS")
@IdClass(DocumentPK.class)
public class CustomerDocument implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6373600479711119252L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="P_ID", nullable=false)
    private String pId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="P_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String pName;

    private     String  p_code;

    /* Getters and setters */
```

Comment: I don't think putting "@EmbeddedId on the id-field instead of the method" makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

your getter and setter for P_ID are wrong

```
   public String getpId() {
      return pId;
   }

   public void setpId(String pId) {
      this.pId = pId;
   }
```

should be

```
public String getPId() {
    return pId;
}

public void setPId(String pId) {
    this.pId = pId;
}
```

Hope that helps

**Update:**
I have used composite keys and how I have configured in my code I have few suggestions.

```
@Embeddable
public class DocumentPK implements Serializable {
    
    @Column(name="P_ID")
    private String pId;

    
    @Column(name="P_NAME")
    private String pName;

    //get set………
}


@Entity
@Table(name="DOCUMENTS")
public class CustomerDocument implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6373600479711119252L;

    @Id
    private     DocumentPK  id; 
    private     String  p_code;//hoping this is not typo better pCode

   //get set ……   
}
```

Set up on similar grounds works for me.

Comment: What is the difference in using @id and @embeddedId?

Comment: @ziggy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868515/difference-using-id-and-embeddedid-for-a-compound-key. May be this link can help you.

Comment: @ziggy I referred hibernate docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177) where by there is difference that with @ EmbeddedId you can skip annotating entity class @ Embeddable but with @ Id its required. I tried using @ Id without @ Embeddable it gives exception **org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Component** just this no extra info like field or class name, using Hibernate 4 currently.

Answer (score 1):

#### Shortly

Add @Access(AccessType.FIELD) to the DocumentPK class (if your implementation supports JPA 2.0) or move annotations from fields to methods (works also with JPA 1.0 implementations).

#### In details

As you see from the error message in the logs: Missing column: **pId**, so it is not about "not finding the **P_ID** column". Following annotation in DocumentPK:

```
@Column(name="P_ID")
```

does not have effect in your case because (from JPA 2.0 specification):

> The access type of an embeddable class is determined by the access
>   type of the entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class in
>   which it is embedded (including as a member of an element collection)
>   independent of whether the access type of the containing class has
>   been explicitly specified or defaulted. A different access type for an
>   embeddable class can be specified for that embeddable class by means
>   of the Access annotation as described above.

Annotations in the fields of DocumentPK do not have effect, because it' access type is AccessType.PROPERTY. This access type is derived from CustomerDocument. CustomerDocument does use property access, because first mapping annotation found is for method (once again from JPA 2.0 specification):

> The default access type of an entity hierarchy is determined by the
>   placement of mapping annotations on the attributes of the entity
>   classes and mapped superclasses of the entity hierarchy that do not
>   explicitly specify an access type.

To make it work you have to change access type in embedded class with @Access annotation or move annotations from fields to methods.

Additionally: your code does not compile, because sometimes you treat pName as String and sometimes as int. Also in "Java-world" it is common practice to use camelCase names instead of underscores as word separators. Also you could consolidate names of fields and methods.