# What is the difference between @EmbeddedId and @Id in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a composite key class annotated with `@Embeddable`. Then I have my entity class using this composite key class as its primary key. I tried to annotate it with either `@Id` and `@EmbeddedId`, both seems to work! Is there any functional difference except for readability?

e.g.

```
@Embeddable public class CompositeKey { ... }
@Entity public class MyEntity {
    @EmbeddedId private CompositeKey id
}

@Embeddable public class CompositeKey { ... }
@Entity public class MyEntity {
    @Id private CompositeKey id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always used ***@EmbeddedId*** in case of Composite primary keys and ***@Id*** in case of simple primary key.

I'm surprised how ***@Id*** is also working.

Other than readability, I believe you can skip using ***@Embeddable*** annotation with ***@EmbeddedId*** but won't be able to do that with ***@Id*** annotation.

Comment: Thanks you, but did you mean "keep using" not "skip using"?

Comment: I meant, you can skip using Embeddable annotation when using EmbeddableId. That is the difference between the both.

Comment: Oh is it? But all the references I read they said @Embeddable is required when using @EmbeddedId?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9842877/7972621 please refer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I referred hibernate docs [Hiberate 3.5 annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177) reference whereby there is the difference that with `@EmbeddedId` you can skip annotating the entity class `@Embeddable` but with `@Id` it's required.

I tried using `@Id` without `@Embeddable` it gives exception:

> org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue cannot be cast to
>
> org.hibernate.mapping.Component